# TCL commenting out items in a list

Tags: tcl

Is there a simple way of commenting out items in a list?

```
set ll [list \
    tom \
#    dick \
#    harry \
    martha]

puts [llength $ll]
```

Quite annoyingly notepad++ and vim highlight the lines with #, and the the line containing martha, fooling me into thinking that they were commented out.

I thought the length would be 2 but it was 6 - it counted the # as separate list items.  I have a fairly long list and sometimes I would like to run the script without those items.  I would like the keep the original items in the list so that the next person modifying it knows what is available and can comment/uncomment the items accordingly.

The only alternative I could think of was if the item in the list is a #, then skip the next item.  Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow configurable content in a data structure, so that you can have every item available but only actually use those that you want to use in the current configuration, it is better to use one of several strategies to select the items to be used, instead of trying to make the interpreter do the selection for you.

One possible way to do this:

```
lmap item [concat {*}{
    tom
    dick
    #harry
    #martha
}] {if {[string match #* $item]} {
        continue
    } else {
        set item
    }}
```

---

In Tcl, only commands can be commented out, and there are pitfalls involved even when you try that.

The `#` syntactic marker is only interpreted as the start of a comment if the name of a command was expected in that place. Everywhere else, it's just a normal character (even if syntax highlighting often mistakes it for a comment).

```
# ceci n'est pas une 'comment'
upvar #0 foo bar
```

To temporarily remove items from a list, for e.g. debugging purposes, it is better to just redo the definition:

```
set ll [list \
    tom \
    dick \
    harry \
    martha]

set ll [list \
    tom \
    martha]
```

The last definition will be used. This can become confusing if the change isn't limited to one editing session. To avoid this, saving the original code and completely rewriting the code in use can be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

See the Scripted List command on the Tcl wiki: http://wiki.tcl.tk/scripted+list

Answer (score 1):

You can't comment out elements like that. Tcl's built-in comment processing only finds comments at points where command names can start, and that's not in the middle of arguments to the `list` command. Or any other command (though some commands take scripts, which can contain comments that are parsed as such when the script is parsed).

If you were building the list like this:

```
set myList {
    a b c
    # commented out
    d e f
}
```

then it would be possible to make things work by post-processing that string before treating it as a list. I do this quite a bit in my longer scripts.

```
set myList [regsub -all -line {^\s*#.*$} $myList ""]
```

It's not a perfect solution as it possible to defeat it by being tricky, but it works fine for me.

*However,* when dealing with list construction like this:

```
set myList [list a b c \
    # commented out \
    d e f]
```

That's much more complicated! The problem is that the newline has already gone by the time the list is written into `myList`; the only workable fix I can think of is to make `source` preprocess the whole script! A way to do that is below. (This is not perfect; some introspection techniques can detect what is going on.)

```
proc source args {
    # Argument parsing; the full works
    set enc [encoding system]
    if {[llength $args] > 1 && [lindex $args 0] eq "-encoding"} {
        set enc [lindex $args 1]
        set args [lrange $args 2 end]
    }
    if {[llength $args] != 1} {
        return -code error \
            "wrong # args: should be \"source ?-encoding name? fileName\""
    }
    set fileName [lindex $args 0]

    # Read in the script
    set f [open $fileName]
    fconfigure $f -encoding $enc -translation auto -eofchar \x1a
    set script [read $f]
    close $f

    # Pre-process the script; note that we're more careful with backslashes here
    set script [regsub -all -line {^\s*#.*([\\]?)$} $script {\1}]

    # Evaluate the script in the caller while setting [info script]
    info script $fileName
    uplevel 1 $script
}
```

Again, this isn't perfect, but it's likely to work fine for your code as long as you define this procedure replacement for `source` before loading in your real code. But I just use the first technique — post-processing the lists I've put comments in *after* construction — instead, and I don't use it for short lists anyway (since those can always have a comment before instead).

Comment: An example of where I do this is [this](http://core.tcl.tk/tclquadcode/artifact/c3c70275a72812e3?ln=49,63) from part of tclquadcode's test/demonstration runner.